# Different path for multilingual view

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

With the Drupal 7 module [Internationalization Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) it was possible to add in a view a different url-path in each active language.

In D8 i found only a solution with a redirect, but i'ts the way i want it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are searching for URL alias for different language.

Go to `/admin/config/search/path/add` where you can add alias for different language.

Comment: i was looking to do it directly into the view, but indeed it' also possible this way